# webos com.webos.service.bluetooth2 monitoring characteristics failed

Tags: bluetooth, webos

i'm developping a webos app and trying to retrieve data from an indoor bike with bluetooth FTMS,i'm using com.webos.service.bluetooth2.
I've already pass the step of discovering devices and connecting to it with `gatt/connect` method. Then i used `gatt/discoverServices` and `gatt/getServices`. From the services of my indoor bike i'm targeting the uuid `00001826-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`(FTMS service) as service and uuid `00002ad2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` (to retrieve data like speed, power, etc...) as characteristic,

So i used `gatt/monitorCharacteristics` with these parameters

```
clientId,
subscribe: true,
service: FTMS_SERVICE,
characteristics: [FTMS_INDOOR_BIKE_DATA]
```

the `clienId` is the id of my devices connected, `FTMS_SERVICE` is the uuid of FTMS, `FTMS_INDOOR_BIKE_DATA` is the uuid of retrieving data of indoor bike (as mentioned before)

i got an error for the monitoring `GATT monitor characteristic failed for characteristic: 00002ad2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`.

my method `gatt/getServices` return the following data

```
{
  "adapterAddress": "18:58:80:9b:37:07",
  "returnValue": true,
  "address": "1c:36:39:33:3b:12",
  "services": [
    {
      "includes": [],
      "characteristics": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": true,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "003",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": true,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "005",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "007",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002ac9-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "009",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        }
      ],
      "service": "00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
      "type": "primary"
    },
    {
      "includes": [],
      "characteristics": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": true
          },
          "characteristic": "00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "012",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": [
            {
              "instanceId": "013",
              "descriptor": "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
              "permissions": {},
              "value": {
                "bytes": []
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "service": "00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
      "type": "primary"
    },
    {
      "includes": [],
      "characteristics": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "016",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "018",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "020",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "022",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "024",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "026",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        }
      ],
      "service": "0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
      "type": "primary"
    },
    {
      "includes": [],
      "characteristics": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": false,
            "notify": true,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "029",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": [
            {
              "instanceId": "030",
              "descriptor": "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
              "permissions": {},
              "value": {
                "bytes": []
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002a38-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "032",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        }
      ],
      "service": "0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
      "type": "primary"
    },
    {
      "includes": [],
      "characteristics": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002acc-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "035",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": false,
            "notify": true,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002ad2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "037",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": [
            {
              "instanceId": "038",
              "descriptor": "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
              "permissions": {},
              "value": {
                "bytes": []
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": true,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002ad3-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "040",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": [
            {
              "instanceId": "041",
              "descriptor": "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
              "permissions": {},
              "value": {
                "bytes": []
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002ad6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "043",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002ad8-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "045",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": true,
            "read": false,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": true,
            "indicate": true
          },
          "characteristic": "00002ad9-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "047",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": [
            {
              "instanceId": "048",
              "descriptor": "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
              "permissions": {},
              "value": {
                "bytes": []
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": false,
            "notify": true,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "00002ada-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
          "instanceId": "050",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": [
            {
              "instanceId": "051",
              "descriptor": "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
              "permissions": {},
              "value": {
                "bytes": []
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "service": "00001826-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
      "type": "primary"
    },
    {
      "includes": [],
      "characteristics": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": true,
            "read": false,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": true,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "49535343-8841-43f4-a8d4-ecbe34729bb3",
          "instanceId": "054",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": false,
            "notify": true,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "49535343-1e4d-4bd9-ba61-23c647249616",
          "instanceId": "056",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": [
            {
              "instanceId": "057",
              "descriptor": "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
              "permissions": {},
              "value": {
                "bytes": []
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "service": "49535343-fe7d-4ae5-8fa9-9fafd205e455",
      "type": "primary"
    },
    {
      "includes": [],
      "characteristics": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "02f00000-0000-0000-0000-00000000ff03",
          "instanceId": "060",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": true,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "02f00000-0000-0000-0000-00000000ff02",
          "instanceId": "062",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": [
            {
              "instanceId": "064",
              "descriptor": "00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
              "permissions": {},
              "value": {
                "bytes": []
              }
            },
            {
              "instanceId": "063",
              "descriptor": "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
              "permissions": {},
              "value": {
                "bytes": []
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": false,
            "read": true,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": false,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "02f00000-0000-0000-0000-00000000ff00",
          "instanceId": "066",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "authenticatedSignedWrites": false,
            "extendedProperties": false,
            "write": true,
            "read": false,
            "notify": false,
            "broadcast": false,
            "writeWithoutResponse": true,
            "indicate": false
          },
          "characteristic": "02f00000-0000-0000-0000-00000000ff01",
          "instanceId": "068",
          "permissions": {},
          "value": {
            "bytes": []
          },
          "descriptors": []
        }
      ],
      "service": "02f00000-0000-0000-0000-00000000fe00",
      "type": "primary"
    }
  ]
}
```

as mentioned in the property of my characteristic, the notify is true and as the doc said if it's true i can retrieve the data (speed, power, cadence, etc...) of my indoor bike.

Is there any process i forgot to setup?

Thanks :)